# Generate font size classes with sass mixin

Tags: sass

I'm trying to generate font size classes with SASS mixin. They will look like `.font-size-20` class with `font-size: 1.25rem` property. I'm using conversion from `px` to `rem` with new Bootstrap 5 function `rfs-value()` but this function in my mixin didn't convert `px` to `rem`.

Here is my mixin:

```css
$font-size-list: 14 16 20 24;

@each $value in $font-size-list {
  .font-size-#{$value} {
     font-size: rfs-value($value + px)!important;
  }
}
```

Output:

```css
.font-size-20 {
   font-size: 20px!important;
}
```

Please repair it to output `font-size` in `rem` but not in `px`.

`rfs-value()` converts a value into a `rem` value if a `px` value is passed, in other cases it returns the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function like this:

```css
@function pxToRem($pxSize) {
  @return $pxSize / 16 + rem;
}
```

And use it in your mixin:

```css
@mixin font-size() {

  $font-size-list: 14 16 20 24;

  @each $value in $font-size-list {
    .font-size-#{$value} {
      font-size: pxToRem($value);
    }
  }
}

@include font-size()
```

The result will be this:

```css
.font-size-14 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.font-size-16 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.font-size-20 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.font-size-24 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `!important`. It just causes issues later down the road. It would be better to architect your system to better handle font sizes. You set a convention with your developers to only set font-sizes using these classes. If you want to use utility classes like these you can't set font-sizes any other way. Then use code reviews to enforce the rule.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. in the example I use !important because @urch also used it in his question. I never use !Important. I will edit my answer without !Important.

Comment: Why we can't concatenate number and 'px' and transfer result to  rfs-value()?

Comment: Michael Turnwall, kroyxlab, I am using !important beqause bootstrap assumes using !important in their font-size utilities

Answer (score 0):

I have modified previous answer and added a sass for loop to generate classes, like font-12, font-13, font-14, etc.

```
@function pxToRem($pxSize) {
  @return $pxSize / 16 + rem;
}
@mixin font-size() {
  @for $size from 12 through 64 {
    .font-#{$size} {
      font-size: pxToRem($size);
    }
  }
}

@include font-size();
```